# Android AutoCompleteTextView Crash on Item Selection (only on HTC Thunderbolt)

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview, htc-android

Have been getting a really weird error recently from an android app I am developing.

Part of the app has a Map view with a list of locations displayed as an AutoCompleteTextView.  On every device and emulator I tested this function performs as expected.  However, whenever a user with an HTC Thunderbolt phone (running 2.3.4) tries to select an item in the list, the application crashes.

Here is my stack trace from the Bug Reports I have received:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at com.package.my.e.onItemClick(Unknown Source) 
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1022) 
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$1300(AutoCompleteTextView.java:99) 
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1597) 
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284) 
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3561) 
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4306) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In logCat "java.lang.NullPointerException"  double click on this error it will navigate you to that line of code which is throwing a null pointer exception and post that code here Along with your Question . thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't replicate this error.  This stack trace is from a bug report sent by another user, and I haven't been able to recreate it.

Comment: Actv on Thunderbolt is kind of broken for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I get when doing Autocompletetextview on Thunderbolt. The white suggestion fields only show suggestions if you press on them. So it seems actv and Thunderbolt is a bad combination.
[image]